# Save for loop result in variable

Tags: python, for-loop

How do I save the results in a `for loop` into a `variable`?
Basically what print does in this example:

```
myList = ['a' ,'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e']
for i in myList:
    print i
```

Result:

```
>>> 
a
b
c
d
e
>>>
```

I want to save exactly this print result into a variable.

Until now I solved it like this:

```
myList = ['a' ,'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e']
for i in myList:
    if "a" in i:
        v1 = i
    if "b" in i:
        v2 = i
    if "c" in i:
        v3 = i

allresults = v1+"\n"+v2+"\n"+v3
print allresults
```

But the problem is if you do not know the length of the list because it is changing all the time (JSON), then you don't get all results.

There needs to be a simpler way and all the infos I found here from other people were related to specific subjects like maths etc.

To be more specific, I am trying to store the result of the for loop into a variable, it's not a question about Lists.

Comment: They are already in a variable, namely `myList`. It's hard to give advice without understanding what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Isn't `myList` in your example, the result you want? Or are you looking at a string representing what this particular for loop produces? In which case, `"\n".join(myList)`... For this particular case. I'm not sure that _you_ understand what it is you're asking....

Comment: What do you mean by "the result of the for loop"? The concatenation of the output from all `print` statements?

Comment: idjaw answered my question, I'm sorry for not being able yet to describe it better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, you seem to want to have some type of variable for each of those items. So, use a dictionary for this.

```
myList = ['a' ,'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e']

my_dict = {}

for idx, val in enumerate(myList): 
    my_dict["v{}".format(idx)] = val
```

So, when you print `my_dict`. You will have:

```
{'v0': 'a', 'v1': 'b', 'v2': 'c', 'v3': 'd', 'v4': 'e'}
```

Does not matter how big the list is, you will have all the keys you need that will be created in there and you can just reference them accordingly.

Example:

```
print(my_dict['v3']) # outputs d
```

And if you want to print out all your values the way you are looking to output them, then all you have to do is this:

`.values` does exactly what it implies. Gets the values of the dictionary. Then, you are making it a string by using the `join` method and separating them by a newline, per '\n'.

```
print('\n'.join(my_dict.values()))
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

If, in the end all you really want to do is output the list "vertically", then the other solutions here suffice, i.e. `print('\n'.join(myList))`

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know, I didnt know that I could transfer every item into a dict and then simply go from there. this makes it way easier working with changing length while still being able to output every entry. I will mark this as accepted answer. Thank you very much and sorry for being unable to explain myself more detailled

Answer (score 2):

I really don't understand why you want to do such a thing, but I believe that you want to do something like this:

```
>>> my_var = '\n'.join(myList)
>>> my_var
'a\nb\nc\nd\ne'
>>> print my_var
a
b
c
d
e
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a string to hold the output and print it all at once.

```
myList = ['a' ,'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e']
str = ""
for i in myList:
    str += i + "\n"
print str
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to stick all the list values together, separated by some text, you should use the join method.

```
myList = ['a' ,'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e']

allresults = "\n".join(myList)
print allresults
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to make a string like your `allresults` there:

1) Start with an emptry string, expand it

```
allresults = ''

for c in MyList:
    if allresults: allresults += '\n'
    allresults += c

print allresults
```

2) Use the builtin `.join()` method of strings to do the exact same

```
allresults = '\n'.join(myList)
print allresults
```

But saving the loop variable into a variable doens't make much sense, `myList` is already that variable.

Comment: This works! Exactly what I needed. I'm trying to debug a certain type of MIME multipart message I'm receiving and I had no better solution to solve the problem than this.